# Python DataFrame particular columns conversion

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, pandas-datareader

Current Data Frame output as below I need another Data Frame

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ursh.png)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame('c:\data\text.csv')

print (df)

My output is as below:

```
   a b    c                                                    d         e

0  1  10 {'a1':40,'b1':60,'c1':90,'d1':100,'e1':50,'f1':75}  10000     899
1  1  65 {'a1':35,'b1':535,c1': 343,'d1':89,'e1':67,'f1':45} 90000     789
```

Assume my index around 50,000 to 1,00,000

I tried:

df1=pd.DataFrame(list(df.c))

print(df1)

```
     a1   b1    c1   d1   e1    f1                          
     40   60    90   100  50   75             
     35   535   343  89   67   45
```

Then I tried

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.a)

df3 = pd.DataFrame(df.b)

df4 = pd.DataFrame(df.d)

df5 = pd.DataFrame(df.e)


frames = [df1,df2,df3,df4,df5]

result = pd.concat(frames)
```

Still I am not able to get the expected result as below:

```
   a  b    a1  b1    c1   d1   e1    f1            d        e                
0  1  10   40  60   90   100  50   75             10000     899
1  1  65   35  535  343  89   67   45             90000      789
```

Comment: Please format your code correctly. It's impossible to tell what you're looking for.

Comment: Hi attached the picture Just click 1(Near to Data Frame)

Comment: Not good enough man. Need to format your code with the proper tags.

Comment: Please refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) on how to post a good pandas question with reproducible results. You're more likely to get help on SO if people are able to easily understand and replicate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you can do :-

Assuming the name of `DataFrame` is `df`,
Convert each `dicts` of `df[c]` to `list`. Now you ned to unzip this list to add to the `DataFrame`. Unzip to get appropriate `list` and to add to `df`.

```
list_abcdef = list(map(list,zip(*[[dic['a1'],dic['b1'],dic['c1'],dic['d1'],dic['e1'],dic['f1']] for dic in df['c']])))
df1 = df[['a','b']]
df1['a1'],df1['b1'],df1['c1'],df1['d1'],df1['e1'],df1['f1'] = list_abcdef
df1['d'],df1['e'] = df['d'],df['e']
```

`df1` should be the `DataFrame` you need. PLease let know if it works for you.

Comment: @thangaraj1980 Please accept the answer if it works. That will help others with same issue.